# How to build Mantle v2 for iOS 7.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, dylib, github-mantle

my project currently targets iOS 7.1 and up. I have built Mantle along with Carthage as described on the [Mantle's GitHub site](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle). But I get the following error when building my project:

> ld: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later
>   (@rpath/Mantle.framework/Mantle) for architecture arm64 clang: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Does somebody know how I could build the `Mantle.framework` for iOS 7.1 (preferably with Carthage) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to target iOS 7.x then you cannot use frameworks as frameworks are only supported from iOS 8.0 onwards. Since Carthage creates frameworks, you also won't be able to use Carthage.

If you still want to use Mantle, either include its files into your project manually or use Cocoapods to build it as a static library using one of the existing [Cocoapods spec files](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/Mantle) for Mantle.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I decided to go the cocoapod way. Currently I can't give you the bounty since SO tells me that I have to wait for 20 hours... But I will assign the bounty tomorrow to you as soon as it's freed.